# Random value from an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have got an array like this.

`NSArray *myArray  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3",@"5",@"45",@"67",nil];`

I want to select a random value from my array and put it into a label.

How can I do it?

Comment: Google "obj-c random number". Use that to get a random index. Done.

Comment: btw stackoverflow is full of "random object from array" questions, I personally have possibly answered 5-6 so far. A little search next time wouldn't hurt

Comment: Even today i gave an answer related to random number....

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
myLabel.text = myArray[arc4random_uniform(myArray.count)];
```

Answer (score 1):

And (now not the only) **correct** solution:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];
NSString *item = array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```